# Customize Point of sale software made in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to customize a POS software made in codeigniter php.I am new to it.Guide me I want to do following changes

1. I want to set cursor on Textfield when user press F8 but the problem is on F8 it is redirecting to another page it is application default behavior. i want to disable this previous effect and want to set cursor on textfield
2. I want to print the sales receipt. Receipt page is showing now by clicking on "Complete sale" button.but i want this when user enters amount in textfield and press enter.

`

```
 <?php
        // Only show this part if there is at least one payment entered.
        if(count($payments) > 0)
        {
        ?>
            <div id="finish_sale">
                <?php echo form_open("sales/complete",array('id'=>'finish_sale_form')); ?>
                <label id="comment_label" for="comment"><?php echo $this->lang->line('common_comments'); ?>:</label>
                <?php echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'comment', 'id' => 'comment', 'value'=>$comment,'rows'=>'4','cols'=>'23'));?>
                <br />
    <br />

            <?php

            if(!empty($customer_email))
            {
                echo $this->lang->line('sales_email_receipt'). ': '. form_checkbox(array(
                    'name'        => 'email_receipt',
                    'id'          => 'email_receipt',
                    'value'       => '1',
                    'checked'     => (boolean)$email_receipt,
                    )).'<br />('.$customer_email.')<br />';
            }

            if ($payments_cover_total)
            {
                echo "<div class='small_button' id='finish_sale_button' style='float:left;margin-top:5px;'><span>".$this->lang->line('sales_complete_sale')."</span></div>";
            }
            echo "<div class='small_button' id='suspend_sale_button' style='float:right;margin-top:5px;'><span>".$this->lang->line('sales_suspend_sale')."</span></div>";
            ?>
        </div>
</form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>`
```

// Javascript  Mycode

```
$(document).keypress(function (e){

    if(e.keyCode==119)
    {

        $("#amount_tendered").focus();
    }
    if(e.keyCode==13)
    {
        $("#finish_sale_button").click();
        $('#finish_sale_form').submit();
        $('#finish_sale_button').attr('action', '<?php echo site_url("sales/complete"); ?>');

    });

    }
        //window.print();

    });
```

//When click on button this function is calling

```
$("#finish_sale_button").click(function()
    {
        if (confirm('<?php echo $this->lang->line("sales_confirm_finish_sale"); ?>'))
        {
            $('#finish_sale_form').submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hire someone. We're not a "free developer" service.

Comment: I have posted the code. you can tell me where m wrong